# Packed object into fundamental type in generic method

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft.JSON library to serialize and deserialize object in generic method. The problem is that fundamental types are parsed differently.

```
public T? GetKey<T>(string key) where T : struct
{
    string content = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault(key, null);
    if (content == null)
        return null;
    object o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
    T v = (T)o;
    return v;
}
```

When the stored value is *"1"* (the *content* variable), the object's inner type is long and I can't cast directly from object to *T=int* (InvalidCastException). The propper approach will be cast the object first to long and then to the int, but because it is generic method, I don't know what the result type will be.
I tried also using `Activator.CreateInstance(o.GetType(), o);` but this returns object once again.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

EDIT: simplified problem

```
string content = "1";
object o = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
int v = /* ??? */;
Debug.Assert(v == 1);
```

Comment: What speaks against using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`?

Comment: Thank you, doesn't work before, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a type. The deserializer can't guess what type it should choose from when deserializing. Pass the passed in generic type parameter through to the DeserializeObject method.

```
public T? GetKey<T>(string key) where T : struct
{
    string content = CrossSettings.Current.GetValueOrDefault(key, null);
    if (content == null)
        return null;
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```